# How can I detect <EOF> of a "CSV data set config" in a groovy script sampler in JMeter?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to know, how it's possible to react on a  in a groovy script.
I'm using a While controller to iterate through all lines in the CSV and generate JMeter variables before my actual testplan. I need to do this several times for different CSV files, therefore I don't want to stop the thread at  in the While controller.

I imagined something like this:

```
if (${CSV_VALUE1} != "<EOF>")
{
    def variableName = sprintf('%1$sVALUE',[${CSV_VALUE2}])
    vars.put(variableName,${CSV_VALUE1});
}
```

CSV_VALUE1 is the value for the JMeter variable and CSV_VALUE2 is the name of the variable.

[Testplan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvfMa.png)

I also appreciate better solutions, which iterate through **every** row of the CSV file and generate JMeter variables according to my conventions of it. A constraint is, that it has to be done in only one single thread group (=> No stopping of threads on EOF)

Comment: Solution: I found out, that my problem actually was a malformed CSV file with quotes for every value in it. So my approach was actually correct and is possible, therefore I answered the question also myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to detect the end of file for a CSV data set by using a simple if-condition with quotes for the executing block:

```
if ("${CSV_VALUE1}" != "<EOF>")
{
    //Code to execute if the condition is satisfied
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "BeanShell" to read "CSV file", below is sample csv file, which has below data

```
answer1,0
answer2,1
answer3,2
...
answerX,X-1
```

To read this file use below "Beanshell" script

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

String filename = "oprosnik_" + vars.get("fileNum") + ".csv";

ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();     

try {
    File file = new File(filename);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new Exception ("ERROR: file " + filename + " not found");
    }

    BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
    String line = null;
    Integer i = 0;

    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
        strList.add(line);
        i++;
    }

    bufRdr.close();            
    counter = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter"));
    if (counter != i) {
        String[] variables = strList.get(counter).split(",");
        vars.put("answer",variables[0]);
        vars.put("answerNum",variables[1]);
        counter++;
        vars.put("counter",Integer.toString(counter));
    }
    else {
            vars.put("answer","<EOF>");
            vars.put("eol","<EOF>");
            vars.put("counter","0");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    IsSuccess = false; 
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
    System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
```

For reference check following [link](https://anadea.info/blog/jmeter-reading-csv-with-beanshell)

Comment: Thanks, that would also be possible, but actually not necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this `<EOF>` case using [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) combination like:

- While Controller: condition `${__javaScript("${CSV_VALUE1}" != "<EOF>",)}`

  - If Controller: condition `"${CSV_VALUE1}" != "<EOF>"`

    - READ - Action Models
    - JSR223 Sampler
    - ...

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for details

Comment: Yes, i tried this before but it never worked for me. The Sampler is called 1 time more with <EOF>, than allowed I actually saw that I have errors in the Log: 
`jmeter.control.IfController: If Controller: error while processing [""e1e78ffd-f900-42fd-a8fa-f3ff9f2fc8e6"" != "<EOF>"]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)`

Comment: I think the problem is the ". It seems that "" with existing id is a problem, on the other hand if I remove the " it's a problem with <EOF>:

`jmeter.functions.JavaScript: Error processing Javascript: [${ACTIONMODELID} != "<EOF>"]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (<cmd>#1)
`

Comment: Finally I brought it to work! My CSV file contained quotes for every value in it! That prevented a successful execution. I need to adapt the way the CSV is generated.